# Equations alignment in Split enviornment

Tags: equations, amsmath

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,setspace,subfig,url,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,setspace,subfig,url,amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % choose whatever margins suit you best
\usepackage{amsmath} % amsmath package provides 'split' environment
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for custom headers
\usepackage{lastpage} % Required to determine the last page for the footer
\usepackage{extramarks} % Required for headers and footers
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to insert images
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
F = \{F_{x} \in  F_{c} &: (|S| > |C|) \\
 &\quad \cap (\text{minPixels}  < |S| < \text{maxPixels}) \\
 &\quad \cap (|S_{\text{conected}}| > |S| - \epsilon) \}




    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}


    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}


    B'&=-\partial \times E,\\
        E'&=\partial \times B - 4\pi j,

    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean flush with the left margin, or do you mean that their left-hand sides should all line up (say, even at the relation)?

Comment: Left-Hand Sides should all line up...

Comment: Then I think you should put all your equations in an `align*` environment. You don't show any text between the `equation*`, so containing them in the same `align*` would have all components line up.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting this error  Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Comment: As of now, your question together with the comments is very unclear. You don't mention anything about a `\caption` in your post. How about you include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem you're experiencing with the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). This would be helpful, since it shows not only what you've tried, but it allows the community to take your code, replicate the problem, and move ahead with trying to resolve it.

Comment: I edited my code here..

Comment: Wow, you load [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) *four* times in your preamble?! That surely does not make this a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  F  &= \begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{\;}l@{}}
      \bigl\{F_x \in F_c : & (|S| > |C|) \\
                      & {}\cap (\text{minPixels} < |S| < \text{maxPixels}) \\
                      & {}\cap (|S_{\text{conected}}| > |S| - \epsilon) \bigr\}
    \end{array} \\
  B' &= -\partial \times E, \\
  E' &= \partial \times B - 4\pi j,
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The alignment is currently set around the relation `=`. If you require it at a different location, let me know.